# Handle multiple parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using a stored procedure to search in my database and filtering the results on a parameter and I need to filter on unknown multiple parameters.

How can I write a stored procedure that handles this??

Here is my stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ComplaintRefListOnDistrict
     @District nvarchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
       ComplaintFullID, CustomerName, Customer_Address, CustomerEmail,
       Date, ContractID, CustomerPhoneNumber,ID, Complaintreference_ID, State
    FROM 
       dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject
    LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.UsersDistricts ON dbo.UsersDistricts.District = dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject.District
    WHERE
       (dbo.UsersDistricts.District = @District)
END
GO
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean , what if @District contains "dist1,dist2", and how to get result based on that?

Comment: By parameter in Stored procedure we mean Input/ Output parameter. like in your case `@District ` is input parameter. When you say multiple parameter i believe you mean multiple and unknown values in @District . If that's correct then please share the string which you wish to pass to this sproc.

Comment: as @ArindamNayak said, what if my Input Parameter '@District' has more than a value?

Comment: @MostafaAb , i am going to post solution for this specifc thing - more than one value, you need to use dynamic SQL to achive this.

Comment: @MostafaAb , Sorry for late answer post, however you can check my answer, it is pretty simple, no need to create a second function to get split value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was telling to use this kind of dynamic SQL.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE ComplaintRefListOnDistrict
         @District nvarchar(max) = ''
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

     declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    set @sql = 'SELECT  
           ComplaintFullID, CustomerName, Customer_Address, CustomerEmail,
           Date, ContractID, CustomerPhoneNumber,ID, Complaintreference_ID, State
        FROM 
           dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject
        LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.UsersDistricts ON dbo.UsersDistricts.District = dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject.District
        WHERE
           (dbo.UsersDistricts.District in (' +  @District + ') )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
```

Comment: Here you don't have to create a util function to split and get values in tabular manner.

Comment: For this to work , you need to pass @District as quoted values with comma separated, if districts are "dist1", "dist2", you need to invoke this sp as 
EXEC  ComplaintRefListOnDistrict '''dist1'',''dist2'''

And if that is integer value, you don't have to put single quote.

Answer (score 1):

First add a helper function, that will split the string you pass to it into rows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS 
    @output TABLE(Data NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 
    BEGIN 
        IF (@end = 0) SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
        INSERT INTO @output (Data) VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

And now everything is very easy. Use the SQL `IN` operator:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ComplaintRefListOnDistrict
     @District nvarchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
       ComplaintFullID, CustomerName, Customer_Address, CustomerEmail,
       Date, ContractID, CustomerPhoneNumber,ID, Complaintreference_ID, State
    FROM 
       dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject
    LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.UsersDistricts ON dbo.UsersDistricts.District = dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject.District
    WHERE
       (dbo.UsersDistricts.District IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.SplitString(@District, ',')))
END
```

HTH.

Comment: You are awesome man, I wish i have enough reputation points to vote up, thank you! I appreciate it so much :)

Comment: @MostafaAb, Nice to know that it helped. :) You may mark this as the answer if it has fully answered your problem, so that it is helpful to others who come searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ComplaintRefListOnDistrict
(
 @District nvarchar(max) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
CSC.ComplaintFullID, CSC.CustomerName, CSC.Customer_Address, CSC.CustomerEmail,
CSC.Date, UD.ContractID, UD.CustomerPhoneNumber,UD.ID, UD.Complaintreference_ID, UD.State
FROM 
  dbo.ComplaintsSmartObject CSC
  LEFT JOIN dbo.UsersDistricts UD
    ON UD.District = CSC.District
WHERE
 (
            UD.District LIKE '%' + @District + '%'
            OR @District IS NULL
            OR @District = ''
            )

    ORDER BY CSC.ComplaintFullID, 
    CSC.CustomerName, 
    CSC.Customer_Address, 
    CSC.CustomerEmail,
CSC.Date, UD.ContractID, UD.CustomerPhoneNumber,UD.ID, UD.Complaintreference_ID, UD.State


END
GO
```

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it well, my stored procedure receives one parameter, I need a stored procedure that Receive unknown number of parameters,

to be clear I have a dropdown list has unstable items, how can I let my stored procedure take them without specifying how many parameter in it? I wanna pass them in one go no matter how many they are, is it possible?
notice that this procedure receives only one item.
 hope its clear

Comment: you are declaring only one parameter and in select statement you are asking to search the required data.So i gave search in where condition

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WHERE clause where you use the unknow parameter or check if it's null

```
WHERE (dbo.UsersDistricts.District = @District OR District IS NULL)
AND (SomeOtherColumn = @OtherParameter OR OtherParameter IS NULL)
```

And so on.